# Append character at autobreaks in listing

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I'm writing a LaTeX document for a hands-on workshop which uses shell/bash commands. I'm making use of the `listings` package to format the chunks of code.

Some of the commands are rather long so I'm making use of `breaklines` and `breakatwhitespace`.

Here's my MWC:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.9,0}

\lstset{%
    columns=fullflexible,
    aboveskip=5pt,
    belowskip=10pt,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{black!85},
    stepnumber=1, 
    numbersep=13pt,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!5},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    xleftmargin=20pt,
    xrightmargin=10pt,
    framesep=5pt,
    framerule=3pt,
    frame=leftline,
    rulecolor=\color{darkgreen},
    tabsize=2,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
cd ~/
time velveth run_25 25 -fmtAuto -create_binary -shortPaired -separate SRR022863_1.fastq.gz SRR022863_1.fastq.gz -shortPaired2 -separate SRR022852_1.fastq.gz SRR022852_2.fastq.gz
time velvetg run_25
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This is displayed as:

[image: Current Styling]

However, I'd like to the listing to include a line continuation character (`\`) at the ends of autobroken lines. Is there a way that listing can do this? This is what I'd like the listing to look like (with or without line numbers on the indented lines) without explicitly putting in the backslash:

[image: Required Styling]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `prebreak=<tokens>` to insert `<tokens>` at the end of the current line:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.9,0}

\lstset{%
    columns=fullflexible,
    aboveskip=5pt,
    belowskip=10pt,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{black!85},
    stepnumber=1, 
    numbersep=13pt,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!5},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    xleftmargin=20pt,
    xrightmargin=10pt,
    framesep=5pt,
    framerule=3pt,
    frame=leftline,
    rulecolor=\color{darkgreen},
    tabsize=2,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
   prebreak=\small\symbol{'134}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
cd ~/
time velveth run_25 25 -fmtAuto -create_binary -shortPaired -separate SRR022863_1.fastq.gz SRR022863_1.fastq.gz -shortPaired2 -separate SRR022852_1.fastq.gz SRR022852_2.fastq.gz
time velvetg run_25
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on the font used, it could be better to replace

```
prebreak=\small\symbol{'134}
```

with

```
prebreak=\textbackslash
```

after loading fontenc with the Cork encoding:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.9,0}

\lstset{%
    columns=fullflexible,
    aboveskip=5pt,
    belowskip=10pt,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{black!85},
    stepnumber=1, 
    numbersep=13pt,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!5},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    xleftmargin=20pt,
    xrightmargin=10pt,
    framesep=5pt,
    framerule=3pt,
    frame=leftline,
    rulecolor=\color{darkgreen},
    tabsize=2,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
   prebreak=\textbackslash
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
cd ~/
time velveth run_25 25 -fmtAuto -create_binary -shortPaired -separate SRR022863_1.fastq.gz SRR022863_1.fastq.gz -shortPaired2 -separate SRR022852_1.fastq.gz SRR022852_2.fastq.gz
time velvetg run_25
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the super-fast feedback. I've posted the images as requested.

Comment: @NathanS.Watson-Haigh I've updated my answer using the desired character.

Comment: Excellent! The use of `\symbol{'134}` instead of `\textbackslash` means that I also get a copy-and-pastable backslash!

Comment: A bit of testing from a LaTeX newbie and my specific use-case. i.e. also need the backslash to be copy-pastable. I prefer the use of `\symbol{'134}` since this works whether or not `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is specified. Whereas, \textbackslash is only copy-pastable if `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is specified.

Comment: @NathanS.Watson-Haigh yes; however if you change to a different monospaced font (using the `beramono` package, for example) then `\symbol{'134}` won't give you a backslash.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the info. I only really started with LaTeX a week or so ago, so I'm on a steeeeep learning curve :)